# Locking records in back-end using relationship in frontend

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to figure out how to protect records in access back-end with a relationship in access front-end.
I have the following table in back-end:
tblSit(linked from back-end)

```
tblSitID(autonumber) ProductID LocationID  
1 1 2  
2 5 1  
3 8 3

temp_tblToMove(table in front-end)  
temp_tblToMoveID(autonumber) tblSitID  
1 1  
2 3
```

what I want to do is move the product from one location to another. The idea is:
I select the record in tblSit that stores locations for each product. Then I insert that ID in temp_tblToMove local table. Then I have a form that in the end will delete the selected records from tblSit and insert them again in tblSit changing LocationID.
I want record locking so that if two users try to move the same product then they get error when trying to delete the record from tblSit.
if I would have temp_tblToMove in back-end then the relationship would prevent record deleting. But I'd like to keep temp_tblToMove in front-end, but here the ralationship doesn't include "Enforce referential integrity".

Thanks for the help.
PS: sorry if I didn't do a good job at explaining what I want.

Comment: Do you want to lock multiple rows in the backend until the user confirms the move, or is the form you mentioned just your way of processing the move ?

Comment: yes. I want to lock those rows, until my form completes the record moving routine

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't just update the existing records?

```
UPDATE tblSit SET Location = NewLocationID WHERE ID = WhicheverID;
```

Comment: can't do that. I select the records that need moving based on multiple tables and criterias. then i go to a form, and here i might remove some of those records, add another, so on and so forth, and i might decide i want to cancel the whole thing by closing the form. at this time i want to release the record locks. in the meanwhile some other user/users might want to do the same thing. maybe the best way to do it is by having the temp_tblToMove table in back-end after all.